# default parameter based on generic

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to see if this is possible.

So this function defines an event that I can later reuse to construct new events with data.

```js
export function defineEvent<D extends Record<string, any> | null = null>(
  name: string,
) {
  
  function result(data: D) {
    return data; // modified for this example
  }

  result.$event = name;

  return result;
}
```

Using it in practice would be

```js
const testEvent = defineEvent<{ name: string }>("testEvent");
testEvent({ name: "Bob" });
```

The issue is that sometimes events don't need data, they can be null. For those instances, I don't want to have to put null for each constructor. Can that be inferred from the generic and not require a parameter?

```js
export const emptyEvent = defineEvent("testEvent");
emptyEvent(null); // I don't want to manually set null since the generic is already null
```

Ideally, I would want to make the generic an empty object instead of null, but not sure if there is generic support to tell if the object is empty.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb1LBN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that helps for sure. I noticed though that the compiler allows for the option of undefined? In a perfect world I would just want to default to an empty object versus null but I'm not sure if you can do a generic check if it's an empty object or not.

Comment: Oh, okay, maybe like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3KR3m)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to clarify that an empty parameter means `undefined`, not `null`.

It's possible using **conditional types** and **rest parameters**. Consider the following code:

```js
// return type of defineFunction<D>(...)
export interface DefineEvent<D extends Record<string, any> | undefined> {
  $event: string;

  (...data: D extends undefined ? [] : [D]): D; // no parameter if D is undefined
}

export function defineEvent<
  D extends Record<string, any> | undefined = undefined
>(name: string): DefineEvent<D> {
  function result(...data: D extends undefined ? [] : [D]) {
    return data[0]; // if you really need null, return data[0] ?? null instead.
  };

  result.$event = name;

  return result as DefineEvent<D>;
}
```